# ASP: A string don't work if I assign a value to it

Tags: javascript, asp-classic

why if I declare a variable without assigning a value I can see it and otherwise not?
For example:

```
<%dim codeSwiper
    %><script>alert(<%=codeSwiper%>);</script>
```

With this code the alert show:*undefined*

```
 <%dim codeSwiper
   codeSwiper=""
    %><script>alert(<%=codeSwiper%>);</script>
```

Here the alert show:*undefined*

```
 <%dim codeSwiper
   codeSwiper="text"
    %><script>alert(<%=codeSwiper%>);</script>
```

In this case no alert is shown!

What's the problem?

Comment: Try `<script>alert("<%=codeSwiper%>");</script>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<%dim codeSwiper
   codeSwiper="text"
    %><script>alert('<%=codeSwiper%>');</script>
```

Note the ' characters around the text you want to alert out.

Comment: To make it even better: `'<%=Replace(codeSwiper, "'", "\'")%>'` so that single quotes won't break it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the javascript token in quotes, i.e

```
<script>alert('<%=codeSwiper%>');</script>
```